# Compiling CUDA + Intel MKL with Eclipse Nsight

Tags: cuda, icc, intel-mkl

I would like to implement mkl_lapack's tridiagonal eigenvalue algorithm `dstevr` in one of my header files

```
#include "mkl.h"

void trideigs(int N, int LDZ, double *Z, double *W, double *D, double *E){

double VL=0.0, VU=1.0, ABSTOL=0.0;
int IL=1, IU=N, M=N, LWORK=20*N, LIWORK=10*N, INFO;

int *ISUPPZ=(int*)malloc(2*M*sizeof(int));
int *IWORK=(int*)malloc(LIWORK*sizeof(int));
W=(double*)malloc(N*sizeof(double));
Z=(double*)malloc(LDZ*M*sizeof(double));
double *WORK=(double*)malloc(LWORK*sizeof(double));

dstevr("V","A",&N,D,E,&VL,&VU,&IL,&IU,&ABSTOL,&M,W,Z,&LDZ,ISUPPZ,WORK,&LWORK,IWORK,&LIWORK,&INFO);
}
```

I managed to change Nsight's default compiler to icc and set the `-mkl` option directly with `-Xcompiler`.

At compile time NVCC Compiler runs successfully, but NVCC Linker fails with the following error message:

> Building target: cuMatlab
>   Invoking: NVCC Linker
>   /usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin/nvcc --cudart static -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -ccbin /opt/intel/bin/icpc --relocatable-device-code=false -gencode arch=compute_52,code=compute_52 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -link -o  "cuMatlab"  ./src/cuMatlab.o   -lcublas -lcusolver -lcufft -lgomp
>   ./src/cuMatlab.o: In function `trideigs(int, int, double*, double*, double*, double*)':
>   /tmp/tmpxft_000045f8_00000000-13_cuMatlab.ii:85694: undefined reference to`dstevr'
>   makefile:59: recipe for target 'cuMatlab' failed
>   make: *** [cuMatlab] Error 1

Do I need to add a library path? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can mix `nvcc`, `icpc` and MKL together, but at least you have to link MKL explicitly with the options both recognized by `icpc` and `nvcc`, such as `-L` and `-l`. '-mkl' is a short-cut for those options only recognized by `icpc`. You could refer to [Intel® Math Kernel Library Link Line Advisor](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor) for the option details.

If you want more specific answers, you could create an example to demo how you plan to compile and link your code.

### Update

According to your update, you have found the place of `-Xcopmiler` for NVCC Compiler. But for NVCC Linker, you only specified `-ccbin` but not `-Xlinker`. You will be able to find `-Xlinker` at a similar place in NVCC Linker page. It is the place you should put `-mkl` to. It will pass suitable options to the linker `icpc`.